# Adding opacity disappearing after delayed animation

Tags: html, css, animation, opacity, transition

What i want to do is make my first line of text kind of zoom+fade in when the page is loaded, and my second line of text 2s after the page is loaded. I got the animations working and the timing using animation-delay, but i just can't figure out how to make the second line of text invisible until start of animation..

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L2wcxg2f/2/

This is my markup:

```
<center>
<h1><div id="line1">First</div><div id="line2">Second</div></h1>
</center>
```

And this is my css:

```
#line1 {animation: onload 2s;}
#line2 {animation: onload 2s; animation-delay: 2s;}
@keyframes onload {from{opacity: 0.0; font-size: 170px;}to{opacity: 1.0; font-size: 120px;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `#line2` `opacity:0` at the start and also `animation-direction: forwards`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2wcxg2f/3/)

Comment: Giving it opacity: 0; makes it disappear when the animation is finished.. Sorry, forgot to mention that. 

Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: @metadog Did you look at the demo? You need to apply `animation-direction:forwards` too, just like my answer suggests